# Ansible playbook shell output

Tags: shell, sed, ansible

I would like to quickly monitor some hosts using commands like ps,dstat etc using ansible-playbook. The `ansible` command itself perfectly does what I want, for instance I'd use:

```
ansible -m shell -a "ps -eo pcpu,user,args | sort -r -k1 | head -n5"
```

and it nicely prints all std output for every host like this:

```
localhost | success | rc=0 >>
0.0 root     /sbin/init
0.0 root     [kthreadd]
0.0 root     [ksoftirqd/0]
0.0 root     [migration/0]

otherhost | success | rc=0 >>
0.0 root     /sbin/init
0.0 root     [kthreadd]
0.0 root     [ksoftirqd/0]
0.0 root     [migration/0]
```

However this requires me to keep a bunch of shell scripts around for every task which is not very 'ansible' so I put this in a playbook:

```
---
-
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - shell: ps -eo pcpu,user,args | sort -r -k1 | head -n5
```

and run it with `-vv`, but the output baiscally shows the dictionary content and newlines are not printed as such so this results in an unreadable mess like this:

```
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "ps -eo pcpu,user,args | sort -r -k1 
head -n5 ", "delta": "0:00:00.015337", "end": "2013-12-13 10:57:25.680708", "rc": 0,
"start": "2013-12-13 10:57:25.665371", "stderr": "", "stdout": "47.3 xxx    Xvnc4 :24
-desktop xxx:24 (xxx) -auth /home/xxx/.Xauthority -geometry 1920x1200\n
....
```

I also tried adding `register: var` and the a 'debug' task to show `{{ var.stdout }}` but the result is of course the same.

Is there a way to get nicely formatted output from a command's stdout/stderr when run via a playbook? I can think of a number of possible ways (format output using sed? redirect output to file on the host then get that file back and echo it to the screen?), but with my limited knowledge of the shell/ansible it would take me a day to just try it out.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/537060/how-to-see-stdout-of-ansible-commands

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The `debug` module could really use some love, but at the moment the best you can do is use this:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - shell: ps -eo pcpu,user,args | sort -r -k1 | head -n5
      register: ps

    - debug: var=ps.stdout_lines
```

It gives an output like this:

```
ok: [host1] => {
    "ps.stdout_lines": [
        "%CPU USER     COMMAND",
        " 1.0 root     /usr/bin/python",
        " 0.6 root     sshd: root@notty ",
        " 0.2 root     java",
        " 0.0 root     sort -r -k1"
    ]
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "ps.stdout_lines": [
        "%CPU USER     COMMAND",
        " 4.0 root     /usr/bin/python",
        " 0.6 root     sshd: root@notty ",
        " 0.1 root     java",
        " 0.0 root     sort -r -k1"
    ]
}
```

Comment: how did you get it to pretty print the results? when i do it the output is all on one line.

Comment: accepted! this is basically geerlingguy's answer, but using stdout_lines instead of stdout gives it reasonably formatted output

Comment: Relevant documentation on the [register](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html#id7) action.

Comment: Is there any way to get stdout and stderr in one?

Comment: @PythonNut yes it is. You can just use: `- debug: var="ps.stdout_lines + [ ps.stderr ]"`

Comment: hi, can you access the register from shell ?

Comment: @Illusionist if by shell you mean the `shell` module, then yes you can, just put the registered variable between double `{{ }}`.

Answer (score 18):

This is a start may be :

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - shell: ps -eo pcpu,user,args | sort -r -k1 | head -n5
      register: ps

    - local_action: command echo item
      with_items: ps.stdout_lines
```

**NOTE:** Docs regarding `ps.stdout_lines` are covered here: [('Register Variables' chapter)](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html).

Comment: it's a start, but the lines are output in what seems a completely random order?

Comment: Ansible will return stdout line-by-line without any sorting (I assume it just will run the different tasks and print the lines as they are received). To keep the lines from each host together, put something like |tr "\n" "~" at the end to put everything into one line and take that apart at the receiving end again

Answer (score 14):

Expanding on what leucos said in his answer, you can also print information with Ansible's humble [`debug`](http://docs.ansible.com/debug_module.html) module:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - shell: ps -eo pcpu,user,args | sort -r -k1 | head -n5
      register: ps

    # Print the shell task's stdout.
    - debug: msg={{ ps.stdout }}

    # Print all contents of the shell task's output.
    - debug: var=ps
```

Comment: this just prints `"msg": "<cpu usage>"` for the first debug task and `"msg": "Hello world!"` for the second one

Comment: For me, I get `"msg": "12.7"` for first debug entry (it just prints the first line of stdout), and the entire stdout printed for second debug entry. I ran the playbook against localhost (127.0.0.1).

Comment: @stijn "Hello world!" is the default value of msg. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/debug_module.html

Answer (score 4):

I found using the *[minimal](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py)* `stdout_callback` with ansible-playbook gave similar output to using ad-hoc ansible.

In your ansible.cfg (Note that I'm on OS X so modify the `callback_plugins` path to suit your install)

```
stdout_callback     = minimal
callback_plugins    = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback
```

So that a `ansible-playbook` task like yours

```
---
-
  hosts: example
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - shell: ps -eo pcpu,user,args | sort -r -k1 | head -n5
```

Gives output like this, like an ad-hoc command would

```
example | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
%CPU USER     COMMAND
 0.2 root     sshd: root@pts/3
 0.1 root     /usr/sbin/CROND -n
 0.0 root     [xfs-reclaim/vda]
 0.0 root     [xfs_mru_cache]
```

I'm using ansible-playbook 2.2.1.0

Answer (score 4):

`ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug ansible-playbook /tmp/foo.yml -vvv`

Tasks with STDOUT will then have a section:

```
STDOUT:

What ever was in STDOUT
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need a specific exit status, Ansible provides a way to do that via **callback plugins**.

[Example](https://gist.github.com/cliffano/9868180). It's a very good option if you need a 100% accurate exit status.

If not, you can always use the [**Debug Module**](http://docs.ansible.com/debug_module.html), which is the *standard* for this cases of use.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

for me, the only one that works (because of register+with_items combination) is this:

```
- name: "download and distribute certs"
  shell: "python3 /tmp/bla.py {{ item.name }}"
  register: python3
  with_items: "{{ my_list }}"

- debug: msg="{{ item.stdout_lines | join("\n") }}"
  with_items: "{{ python3['results'] }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally have several shell or command calls in a playbook and gather that's output to different variables. At the end I sum up the information and list all at once like so:

```
- ansible.builtin.shell: "df -h"
  register: disk

- ansible.builtin.shell: "free -m"
  register: mem
```

.....

```
- name: Summarize
  local_action: ansible.builtin.debug var={{ item }}
  become: no
  with_items: 
    - disk.stdout_lines
    - mem.stdout_lines
```

if you call it with

```
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=minimal ansible-playbook getServerInfo.yml
```

it gives a nice, clean output

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not relevant if you're looking to do this ONLY using ansible. But it's much easier for me to have a function in my `.bash_profile` and then run `_check_machine host1 host2`

```
function _check_machine() {
    echo 'hostname,num_physical_procs,cores_per_procs,memory,Gen,RH Release,bios_hp_power_profile,bios_intel_qpi_link_power_management,bios_hp_power_regulator,bios_idle_power_state,bios_memory_speed,'
    hostlist=$1
    for h in `echo $hostlist | sed 's/ /\n/g'`;
    do
        echo $h | grep -qE '[a-zA-Z]'
        [ $? -ne 0 ] && h=plabb$h
        echo -n $h,
        ssh root@$h 'grep "^physical id" /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u | wc -l; grep "^cpu cores" /proc/cpuinfo |sort -u | awk "{print \$4}"; awk "{print \$2/1024/1024; exit 0}" /proc/meminfo; /usr/sbin/dmidecode | grep "Product Name"; cat /etc/redhat-release; /etc/facter/bios_facts.sh;' | sed 's/Red at Enterprise Linux Server release //g; s/.*=//g; s/\tProduct Name: ProLiant BL460c //g; s/-//g' | sed 's/Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release //g; s/.*=//g; s/\tProduct Name: ProLiant BL460c //g; s/-//g' | tr "\n" ","
         echo ''
    done
}
```

E.g.

```
$ _machine_info '10 20 1036'
hostname,num_physical_procs,cores_per_procs,memory,Gen,RH Release,bios_hp_power_profile,bios_intel_qpi_link_power_management,bios_hp_power_regulator,bios_idle_power_state,bios_memory_speed,
plabb10,2,4,47.1629,G6,5.11 (Tikanga),Maximum_Performance,Disabled,HP_Static_High_Performance_Mode,No_CStates,1333MHz_Maximum,
plabb20,2,4,47.1229,G6,6.6 (Santiago),Maximum_Performance,Disabled,HP_Static_High_Performance_Mode,No_CStates,1333MHz_Maximum,
plabb1036,2,12,189.12,Gen8,6.6 (Santiago),Custom,Disabled,HP_Static_High_Performance_Mode,No_CStates,1333MHz_Maximum,
$
```

Needless to say function won't work for you as it is. You need to update it appropriately.

Comment: The output isn't bad, but one of the points of ansible is I do not have to bother with hostlist/ssh/for loops etc. So I'm not going to drop the convenience of that for a function :P

Comment: You're not answering the question. "... using ansible-playbook"

Comment: +1 for pointing out that there may be a better/easier tool for the job. Just because Ansible is the latestgreatest doesn't mean we need to kill the chicken with a machine gun. Ansible is "used for IT tasks such as configuration management, application deployment, intraservice orchestration, and provisioning".  The questioner simply wants to monitor his systems with ps output. Sorry, but Ansible ain't magic. You're going to need an inventory somewhere. And you'll need to "bother" with something- if not ssh, then Ansible. Finally, if a for loop is that hard, well... I guess there's Ansible.

Comment: Hi @MikeS Sure but whether Ansible is the correct tool for the job, I think is another question, to the more direct one of how to format Ansible output. He also might be using Ansible for something else so the overhead is worth it. That's a whole other discussion.

Comment: You're right. I guess I was reacting to stijn's comment, where he talks about how convenient Ansible is as a tool to frontend loops. I see so many comments about how easy Ansible is, and then we have a question like this, with all sorts of "...it didn't work for me..." comments and such. Just to reasonably print output? Yeesh, methinks Ansible is out of its league on this one. But only this one; you're right- he did ask about Ansible and far be it for me to judge his needs. I hate seeing that on StackOverflow, too.