# How to get more usable error messages from ansible-playbook?

Tags: python, ansible

`ansible-playbook` gives me errors that look like this:

```
fatal: [test.example.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "./manage.py migrate --noinput
--pythonpath=/srv/virtualenv/myapp/bin/python3", "failed": true, "msg": "\n:stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"./manage.py\", line 10, in <module>\n    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)\n  File \"/srv/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py\", line 354, in execute_from_command_line\n    utility.execute()\n  File \"/srv/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py\", line 303, in execute\n    settings.INSTALLED_APPS\n  File \"/srv/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py\", line 48, in __getattr__\n    self._setup(name)\n  File \"/srv/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py\", line 44, in _setup\n    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)\n  File \"/srv/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py\", line 92, in __init__\n    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)\n  File \"/srv/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py\", line 126, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _gcd_import\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 969, in
_find_and_load\n  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked\nImportError: No module named 'myapp.settings'\n", "path": "/srv/virtualenv/myapp/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", "state": "absent", "syspath": ["/tmp/ansible_OoxaWI", "/tmp/ansible_OoxaWI/ansible_modlib.zip", "/usr/lib/python2.7", "/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu", "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk", "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old", "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload", "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages", "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"]}
```

Of course I could copy this and paste it into `ipython` to get a more usable view on things, i.e.

```
fatal: [test.example.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "./manage.py migrate --noinput --pythonpath=/srv/virtualenv/myapp/bin/python3", "failed": true, "msg": "
:stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/srv/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/srv/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/srv/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/srv/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/srv/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/srv/virtualenv/myapp/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'myapp.settings'
", "path": "/srv/virtualenv/myapp/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", "state": "absent", "syspath": ["/tmp/ansible_OoxaWI", "/tmp/ansible_OoxaWI/ansible_modlib.zip", "/usr/lib/python2.7", "/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu", "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk", "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old", "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload", "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages", "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"]}
```

But I'd like `ansible` to do that for me. How can I do that?

This is related but doesn't look like solution to my problem: [Ansible playbook shell output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563639/ansible-playbook-shell-output)

Comment: You should actually never see errors like this. The Ansible project considers it a bug any time they give a stacktrace instead of catching the bug with a more user-friendly error. File an issue on their GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

Increase the verbosity. Add `-vvvv` at the end of ansible-playbook command. It will set the verbosity to 4 and that much logs are good enough most of the time.

Comment: where exactly? can you show an example? l am getting syntax errors here

Comment: In the command line:-
$ ansible-playbook 'playbook_name '-vvvv

Answer (score 1):

Ansible allows you to control its output by using [callback plugins](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#callbacks) and provides a few optional callbacks [out of the box](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback).

To configure them simply set the [`callback_plugs` option](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#callback-plugins) in `ansible.cfg`:

```
callback_plugins = ~/.ansible/plugins/callback:/usr/share/ansible/plugins/callback
```

To get Ansible to print the newlines rather than render them as `\n`s you could develop your own callback or simply use the [`human_log`](https://gist.github.com/cliffano/9868180) callback plugin developed by [Cliffano Subagio](http://blog.cliffano.com/2014/04/06/human-readable-ansible-playbook-log-output-using-callback-plugin/).

For Ansible 2 compatibility (the plugin system was rewritten in the version upgrade from Ansible 1.x) an equivalent was written by [n0ts](https://github.com/n0ts/ansible-human_log).